# postfix nothing send email port 25

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am trying to configure the Postfix Mail server. Ready I made the configuration in postfix and devecot (imap / pop). I can receive emails on my server, but I can't send emails to other servers.

im using ec2 aws Free tier eligible

**master.cf**

```
# -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
# -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps inet n - y - - smtpd
# -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
# -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
# -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
# -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
# -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
# -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
# -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
# -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
# -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
# -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628 inet n - y - - qmqpd
pickup unix n - y 60 1 pickup
cleanup unix n - y - 0 cleanup
qmgr unix n - n 300 1 qmgr
#qmgr unix n - n 300 1 oqmgr
tlsmgr unix - - y 1000? 1 tlsmgr
rewrite unix - - y - - trivial-rewrite
bounce unix - - y - 0 bounce
defer unix - - y - 0 bounce
trace unix - - y - 0 bounce
verify unix - - y - 1 verify
flush unix n - y 1000? 0 flush
proxymap unix - - n - - proxymap
proxywrite unix - - n - 1 proxymap
smtp unix - - y - - smtp
relay unix - - y - - smtp
-o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
# -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq unix n - y - - showq
error unix - - y - - error
retry unix - - y - - error
discard unix - - y - - discard
local unix - n n - - local
virtual unix - n n - - virtual
lmtp unix - - y - - lmtp
anvil unix - - y - 1 anvil
scache unix - - y - 1 scache
postlog unix-dgram n - n - 1 postlogd
#
# ====================================================================
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent. See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop unix - n n - - pipe
flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
# lmtp cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
# mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
# virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus unix - n n - - pipe
# user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix - n n - - pipe
# flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp unix - n n - - pipe
flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail unix - n n - - pipe
flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp unix - n n - - pipe
flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n n - 2 pipe
ifmail unix - n n - - pipe
flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp unix - n n - - pipe
flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n n - 2 pipe
flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman unix - n n - - pipe
flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
${nexthop} ${user}
```

**main.cf**

```
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.financeinvestimento.com.br
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, financeinvestimento.com.br, localhost.financeinvestimento.com.br, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks =  172.31.16.0/20  127.0.0.0/8 3.19.239.92
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

**mail.log**

```
Oct 23 18:50:55 mail postfix/postfix-script[2608]: starting the Postfix mail system
Oct 23 18:50:55 mail postfix/master[2610]: daemon started -- version 3.3.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Oct 23 18:51:06 mail postfix/pickup[2623]: 4E3993F0E5: uid=0 from=<root@mail.financeinvestimento.com.br>
Oct 23 18:51:06 mail postfix/cleanup[2629]: 4E3993F0E5: message-id=<20201023185106.4E3993F0E5@mail.financeinvestimento.com.br>
Oct 23 18:51:06 mail postfix/qmgr[2624]: 4E3993F0E5: from=<root@mail.financeinvestimento.com.br>, size=410, nrcpt=1 (queue active)




Oct 23 18:51:36 mail postfix/smtp[2631]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.10.27]:25: Connection timed out
Oct 23 18:52:06 mail postfix/smtp[2631]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.177.26]:25: Connection timed out
Oct 23 18:52:36 mail postfix/smtp[2631]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.175.27]:25: Connection timed out
Oct 23 18:53:06 mail postfix/smtp[2631]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.217.27]:25: Connection timed out
Oct 23 18:53:36 mail postfix/smtp[2631]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.186.26]:25: Connection timed out
Oct 23 18:53:36 mail postfix/smtp[2631]: 4E3993F0E5: to=<maromaporra@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=150, delays=0.02/0.01/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.186.26]:25: Connection timed out)
```

How i can resolve that?

Comment: You have to switch to another cloud provider, because AWS does not allow new accounts to use outbound TCP port 25.

Comment: what u mean??? if i use normally paid them let me use port 25?

Comment: Amazon chooses whether or not to allow port 25 Outbound on a per-customer per-needs basis. Unfortunately with the MASSIVE amount of "free" servers being used by malicious users to spread spam, etc. it makes sense that CLoud Providers like AWS block outgoing Port 25 mail. You probably need to either contact AWS about removing the block. or switch to a different cloud provider (probably won't find one for 'free' though that won't block 25, because of how heavily it is used in email phishing/spam/malware distribution).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to [remove the block of outgoing connections on port 25](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/) imposed by AWS.

Comment: Unfortunately these requests are consistently denied for new AWS users. I know from experience! :(

Comment: i will check with them

Comment: i account got in amazon 2 months probly i will be block?

Comment: We can't possibly know what aws does. Nor is it really Ubuntu related...

Comment: A typical canned response that you will get from AWS: Thank you for submitting your request to have the email sending limit removed from your account and/or for an rDNS update. This account, or those linked to it, have been identified as having at least one of the following:
* A history of violations of the AWS Acceptable Use Policy
* A history of being not consistently in good standing with billing
* Not provided a valid/clear use case to warrant sending mail from EC2
Unfortunately, we are unable to process your request at this time, please consider looking into the Simple Email Service..